# Color Each Line of `align` Environment with a Different Color

Tags: math-mode, formatting, color, align, mathjax

I am trying to have different colors to different lines within an `align` / `aligned` environment. It seems the `&` symbol is causing some issues.

I want to color each line of the following:

```latex
\begin{align*}
f \left( \alpha x + \beta y \right) & = \alpha f \left( x \right) + \beta f \left( y \right) \\
f \left( \mathcal{S} x  \right) & = \mathcal{S} f \left( x \right), \; \mathcal{S}: \text{Shift Operator}
\end{align*}
```

[image]

This will fail (MathJaX environment):

```latex
\begin{align*}
{\color{Cyan} f \left( \alpha x + \beta y \right) & = \alpha f \left( x \right) + \beta f \left( y \right)} \\
{\color{Magenta} f \left( \mathcal{S} x  \right) & = \mathcal{S} f \left( x \right), \; \mathcal{S}: \text{Shift Operator}}
\end{align*}
```

While removing the `&` will make it work yet with no alignment:

```latex
\begin{align*}
{\color{Cyan} f \left( \alpha x + \beta y \right) = \alpha f \left( x \right) + \beta f \left( y \right)} \\
{\color{Magenta} f \left( \mathcal{S} x  \right) = \mathcal{S} f \left( x \right), \; \mathcal{S}: \text{Shift Operator}}
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Is there a way around this?

**Remark 001**: It will also be great to have a solution which works for matrices (Per element).

**Remark 002**: It is better be the solution to be compatible with MathJaX.

Comment: independent of color you can not have a `{` in one tabular or align cell that matches a `}` in a different cell.

Comment: use `\color{Cyan}`  with no additional `{}` at the start of each cell.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I understand. So how could one achieve different colors? As it seems ``\color` requires using those.

Comment: I don't understand your question, sorry, also you have provided no example anyone can run, how have you defined `Cyan` or `Magenta` you can use any colours you have defined using `color` or `xcolor` packages.  `\color` does not need the leading brace `{\color`  just delete that, and the matching `}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I am just using any MathJaX supported environment. For instance just paste the code in this site text box or https://latex.codecogs.com/eqneditor/editor.php. Anyhow, your comment gave me the solution. If you post it as an answer  I will mark it. Thanks!

Comment: note pure mathjax is off topic here, you need to be able to phrase it as a tex question, even though the answer may be usable in mathjax (which doesn't use tex) (but your answer is fine in anycase:-)

Answer (score 1):

Following the comments by @[DavidCarlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) the issue is using `{\color{<SomeColor>} ... }` which breaks the environment.

We can treat each side of `&` as a group.
Then the solution becomes:

```latex
\begin{align*}
\color{Cyan} f \left( \alpha x + \beta y \right) & \color{Cyan} = \alpha f \left( x \right) + \beta f \left( y \right) \\
\color{Magenta} f \left( \mathcal{S} x  \right) & \color{Magenta} = \mathcal{S} f \left( x \right), \; \mathcal{S}: \text{Shift Operator}
\end{align*}
```

[image]

It means replicating the color on each side of `&` yet it will work.